# Make textboxes in java show only information

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, textbox

I want my textboxes in java to show information without people being able to type into them. They should be read-only. Can anyone help?

Comment: swing or what are u using?

Comment: Are you using SWT or Swing or AWT or JavaFX or ...?

Comment: I'm using java.swing and AWT - sorry should've specified that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of swing : [JTextField#setEditable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable%28boolean%29)

```
JTextField box = new JTextField(TEXT);
... init stuff
box.setEditable(false);
```